# How many managed to native (and vice versa) transitions?

Tags: c#, .net, com, native, managed

I have an application that uses several components some written in C# and some written in VB6 and they are interacting via COM Interop.

In the context of some performance problem analysis, I would like to find out the number of transitions between managed and native code (and vice versa) that occur during the execution of my app.

Is there a way to get that info? I looked for a Perfmon counter but only found the number of marshalling.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can log all your calls to unmanaged code from your managed code and vice versa, this will involve modifying your code in both sides, but i think this will give enough flexibility to add some other customs stats like the time it takes the call.